# In bash, how can I use a here document but then open stdin?

Tags: bash, ssh, ssh-tunneling

My example is that I'm tunneling through a server and want to create a command to type in a password but leave stdin open once that's done. For example I need to sudo to a different user everytime I login to this remote host. So I do something like:

```
ssh -p $tunnel_port $me@localhost -t "sudo -S -u $_remoteUser -i" <<< "$( findPassword )"
```

'findPassword' is a function that gets my password out of a password manager

This closes the connection, how do I keep the connection open after the password has been written to stdin for sudo?

Comment: Ordinarily, `sudo` doesn't read from stdin at all, but opens the terminal directly, presumably to deal with just this problem. I don't think there's an easy way to feed data, send EOF, then feed more data in a way that applications will accept. `expect`, maybe.

Comment: `-S` causes sudo to read from stdin.

Comment: Use something that passes the stdin afterwards, e.g. `cat`: `( findPassword; cat ) | ssh ........`

Comment: I tried your suggestion to pipe the password in instead of using the here document `<<<` but got the same result where the connection is closed after the password is sent over stdin. I want to connection to remain open. And I can't use `cat` in either case because cat waits for the end-of-file before proceeding. It would allow me to add custom input if I know what's coming after `ssh` connects but it's not interactive.

Answer (score 0):

You have the quoting such that STDIN of the ssh command is being fed by findPassword. You want the STDIN of the sudo command to be fed by findPassword.

`ssh -p $tunnel_port $me@localhost -t "echo $(findPassword) | sudo -S -u $_remoteUser -i"`

or

`ssh -p $tunnel_port $me@localhost -t "sudo -S -u $_remoteUser -i < $(findPassword)"`

Comment: Wouldn't `< $(findPassword)` try to read from a filename of whatever that variable expands out to?

Comment: Not that with these recommendations, `findPassword` will run on the remote machine. In this case the remote machine is `localhost`, so it's not an issue. But conceptually, this is worth keeping track of. Is there some problem with feeding the STDIN to `ssh`? Won't it just pass that on to the process running on the remote machine? I'd expect @Arthur2e5's suggestion (in a comment to the question) to work.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've setup a tunnel to a remote server. So while I'm connecting to a port on localhost, the terminal is connected to a remote server. You are correct that Mark's suggestion won't work because he's changed the logic to run `findPassword` on the remote server when in fact it needs to run on my local machine (hence the here document)